# Bootstrap 5 Carousel showing only control and not contents

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I am working on an HTML site and I am using the bootstrap 5 frameworks.

MY GOAL is to add bootstrap 5 Carousel in my section next to an image, like show in this image.

> [https://imgur.com/a/JSvH2nw]

I have directly copied  Carousel code from bootstrap docs here is the link

> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/carousel/#slides-only

But for some reason, the Carousel is not showing any content it is only showing controls and slider buttons like this

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/CJdiE.jpg

what m i doing wrong?

```html
<html lang="de">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">



  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">



  <!-- Google Fonts -->
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Playfair+Display:wght@400;500;600;700;800;900&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,300;1,400&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Bootstrap icon -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.8.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container pt-5">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xl-8 col-lg-6 text-sm-center  ">
        <div id="carouselExampleDark" class="carousel carousel-dark slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>First slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" class="d-block w-100" alt="..." />
              <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block">
                <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="prev">
                <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
              </button>
          <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleDark" data-bs-slide="next">
                <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
              </button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xl-4 col-lg-6  custmcol mx-auto text-center">
        <img class="img-fluid sidewhyusimg " src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/000/fff" alt="cleaningImage">
      </div>
      <span class=" shadow-do text-center"><a href="#" class=" btn btn-primary mainbtn mx-auto mt-5  ">Mehr
              erfahren</a></span>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.9.0/js/bootstrap- -->

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace `...` with actual image link
where the img tag is in your html code

```
<img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

like this :

```
<img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

**Update:**

*if you want carousel without image you can do that by following:*

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="carousel-item active" data-bs-interval="10000" >
                  <!-- <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/10/29/14/38/web-1012467__340.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> -->
                  <div class="">
                    <h5>First slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item" data-bs-interval="2000">
                  <!-- <img src="https://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-dotted-banner-background_1035-18160.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> -->
                  <div class="">
                    <h5>Second slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-item">
                  <!-- <img src="https://static.vecteezy.com/system/resources/thumbnails/001/234/358/small/modern-blue-halftone-banner-background.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="..."> -->
                  <div class="">
                    <h5>Third slide label</h5>
                    <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Simple trick: just remove the img tags from the html and remove `carousel-caption` class from the caption text div

**alternatively** you can use owl carousel to create beautiful carousels just like what you want

Here is a jsbin link i created with your code.
https://jsbin.com/rufivuwije/edit?html,output

Comment: Thanks for the answer but as you may have seen in my attached image i what only text slider no image, Is there any way to do that?

Comment: I have updated the answer and the jsbin as well. Please do check

Comment: Thanks for the help much appreciated removing ~carousel-caption ~ did the trick and after added some padding to the ~<p>~.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the image address in your code should be changed to your own image address.

```
<img src="..." class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

Comment: how can only make text slider i.e without image like this [link] https://imgur.com/a/JSvH2nw